# angularjs - is it not possible to add ng- attributes on a directive?

Tags: angularjs, compilation, directive

What I would like to be able to do is "wrap" the behavior of an ng-hide for a "permissions" directive...  so I can do the following

```
<a href="/" permit="false">Hide me</a>
```

All is fine if I decide to simply "remove" the element from the dom; however, if I try to add an ng-hide and then recompile the element.  Unfortunately, this causes an infinite loop

```
angular.module('my.permissions', []).
  directive 'permit', ($compile) ->
    priority: 1500
    terminal: true
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      element.attr 'ng-hide', 'true' # ultimately set based on the user's permissions
      $compile(element)(scope)
```

OR

```
angular.module('my.permissions', []).directive('permit', function($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 1500,
    terminal: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.attr('ng-hide', 'true'); // ultimately set based on the user's permissions
      return $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

I've tried it without the priority or terminal to no avail.  I've tried numerous other permutations (including removing the 'permit' attribute to prevent it from continually recompiling, but what it seems to come down to is this: there doesn't seem to be a way to modify an element's attributes and recompile inline through a directive.

I'm sure there's something I'm missing.

Comment: why do you need custom directive if you want to do just ng-hide="false"?

Comment: The real code will determine whether to do true or false on the hide based on permissions the user has

Comment: you can do $(element).hide() $(element).show() inside your directive. you do not need ng-hide for this.

Comment: @MajoB your solution assumes that the OP is using JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes that you want to watch the changes of the `permit` attribute if it changes and hide the element as if it was using the `ng-hide` directive. One way to do this is to watch the `permit` attribute changes and then supply the appropriate logic if you need to hide or show the element. In order to hide and show the element, you can replicate how angular does it in the `ng-hide` directive in their **[source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L313)**.

```
directive('permit', ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    multiElement: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(attr.permit, function (value){

        // do your logic here
        var condition = true; 
        // this variable here should be manipulated in order to hide=true or show=false the element. 
        // You can use the value parameter as the value passed in the permit directive to determine 
        // if you want to hide the element or not.

        $animate[condition ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'](element, 'ng-hide');

        // if you don't want to add any animation, you can simply remove the animation service
        // and do this instead:
        // element[condition? 'addClass': 'removeClass']('ng-hide');
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I ran into some issues with scope.$watch(attr.permit and ended up using the following code:  attr.$observe('permit', function(value) {  element['addClass']('ng-hide'); }

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('my.permissions', []).directive('permit', function($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 1500,
    terminal: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function(){
         var method = scope.$eval(attrs.permit) ? 'show' : 'hide';
         element[method]();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this directive. This works like ng-if but it checks for permissions.

```
appModule.directive("ifPermission", ['$animate', function ($animate) {
    return {
        transclude: 'element',
        priority: 600,
        terminal: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        $$tlb: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
            var block, childScope;

            var requiredPermission = eval($attr.ifPermission);
            // i'm using global object you can use factory or provider
            if (window.currentUserPermissions.indexOf(requiredPermission) != -1) {

                    childScope = $scope.$new();
                    $transclude(childScope, function (clone) {
                        clone[clone.length++] = document.createComment(' end ifPermission: ' + $attr.ngIf + ' ');
                        // Note: We only need the first/last node of the cloned nodes.
                        // However, we need to keep the reference to the jqlite wrapper as it might be changed later
                        // by a directive with templateUrl when it's template arrives.
                        block = {
                            clone: clone
                        };
                        $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
                    });
             }
        }
    };
}]);
```

usage:

```
<div if-permission="requiredPermission">Authorized content</div>
```